# How to find lantronix devices in the local network by Java.io API

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to find lantronix devices on a LAN through Java using the Java.io. * API

I need to use an UDP protocol in order to broadcast al pcs in the network by the port 30718. When I broadcast them I'll get a response from the devices on the network.

I need some way to make a UDP broadcast an retrieve the pc's responses on the network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
package testbroadcastudp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
* @since 03-05-2017
* @author jsanchez
*/
public class UDPBroadcastToLantronixDevices {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Port 30718 for sent at Lantronix devices
        try (DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(30718)) 
        {//30718 50000
            byte[] queryMsg = new byte[4];
            queryMsg[0] = (byte)0x00;
            queryMsg[1] = (byte)0x00;
            queryMsg[2] = (byte)0x00;
            queryMsg[3] = (byte)0xF6;//Dec 246
            String testByte = new String(queryMsg,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

            serverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                queryMsg,
                queryMsg.length,
                InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.255"),//192.168.1.201
                30718
            );
            //Send broadcast
            serverSocket.send(datagramPacket);
            //Close Broadcast socket to close the 30718 port.
            serverSocket.close();
            //Start the listening from the server
            receive();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void receive(){
        //Port 30718 for listen Lantronix devices
        try (DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(30718)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

            // Set a timeout of 3000 ms to listen in the server side
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0,             buffer.length);

                /**
                * The receive method will wait for 3000 ms for data.
                * After that, the server will throw a timeout exception.
                */
                clientSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                System.out.println("Listen on " + datagramPacket.getAddress() + " from " + datagramPacket.getData().toString() + " port " + datagramPacket.getPort());
                String receivedMessage = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
                //Decode to get the 0xF7 or '÷' in the byte[4] for a Lantronix Devices in the LAN
                receivedMessage = new String(datagramPacket.getData(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                System.out.println(receivedMessage);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout. Client is closing.");
        }
    }
}
```